# Square paymentform not formatting iframes correctly on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, square-connect

I'm having a peculiar problem. I've built an html5 app and I'm using Square as a payment processor and I have included the paymentForm into my webpage. PaymentForm seems to not be formatting any of the elements correctly on Android. For instance, if I type into the cardNumber input field on Android the text isn't broken up into 4 digits "**** **** **** ****" and when typing into expirationDate it doesn't create the slash between month and year "mm/yy". The odd thing is it works on Chrome on my pc, it works on my iOS app and Safari on both my iOS device and my Mac. However, it doesn't work when using my Android app or Chrome on my Android device.

JavaScript where I create SqPaymentForm

```
// Initializes payment form.
var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
    applicationId: applicationId,
    inputClass: 'sq-input',
    inputStyles: [
        {
            fontSize: '16px'
        }
    ],
    cardNumber: {
        elementId: 'sq-card-number',
        placeholder: '**** **** **** ****'
    },
    cvv: {
        elementId: 'sq-cvv',
        placeholder: 'cvv'
    },
    expirationDate: {
        elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
        placeholder: 'mm/yy'
    },
    postalCode: {
        elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
        placeholder: '*****'
    },
    callbacks: {
        // Called when SqPaymentForm completes a request to generate a card
        // nonce, even if the request failed because of an error.
        cardNonceResponseReceived: function(errors, nonce, cardData){
            if(errors){
                $.mobile.loading("hide");
                var eString = '';
                errors.forEach(function(error){
                    eString += "<p>" + error.message + "</p>";
                });
                $("#paymentErr").html(eString);
                $("#pay").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#back").prop("disabled", false);
                return;
            }
            /*
                Call cloud code to process payment with nonce
            */
            charge(nonce, cardData["billing_postal_code"]);
        },
        unsupportedBrowserDetected: function(){
            $("#paymentErr").text("This browser is currently not supported by Square, our payment processor");
        },
        inputEventReceived: function(inputEvent){
            switch(inputEvent.eventType){
                case 'focusClassAdded':
                    break;
                case 'focusClassRemoved':
                    break;
                case 'errorClassAdded':
                    break;
                case 'errorClassRemoved':
                    break;
                case 'postalCodeChanged':
                    break;
            }
        },
        paymentFormLoaded: function(){
            // Perform actions after payment done loading
        }
    }
});
paymentForm.build();
```

HTML form

```
<form id="payment-form">
    <p class="err" id="paymentErr"></p>
    <div class="saved" id="saved"></div>
    <label>Card Number</label>
    <div id="sq-card-number"></div>
    <label>CVV</label>
    <div id="sq-cvv"></div>
    <label>Expiration Date</label>
    <div id=sq-expiration-date></div>
    <label>Postal Code</label>
    <div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
</form>
```

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIIUj.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNVHQ.png)

Comment: Hmm, that is weird! What version of Android and chrome are you using? Any code you could share to help us debug? I just loaded the form on an android emulator, and everything seemed to work out ok.

Comment: @tristansokol I just updated by post with relevant code. I'm using Android 4.4.4 and Chrome version 54.0.2840.68

Comment: Hmm, I still wasn't able to reproduce on an emulated kitkat device. I've tried reproducing your form here: [https://tristansokol.github.io/connect-api-examples/](https://tristansokol.github.io/connect-api-examples/) can you try navigating to it with your phone and seeing if it works?

Comment: I navigated there but there weren't any inputs.

Comment: @tristansokol Can confirm I don't see any inputs on that page either.

Comment: Whoops! try it now. Do you have your device open for USB debugging? It would be great to know if you are getting any errors on your page or webview.

Comment: Ok, navigated there, got same problem and this is there error I saw Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buildStylesForScreenWidth' of null
    at r (https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber:28:11564)
    at s (https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber:28:11737)

Comment: Something else I just noticed. It doesn't format while typing but it does after the input becomes unfocused. Also, if I type on the page from chrome debug tools everything works fine but again not from the android device.

Comment: And this is both for chrome and webviews on your mobile for my example site? Is that the only error you are getting?

Comment: And does your app do anything weird with resizing the screen?

Comment: Correct. I don't think I'm doing any kind of screen resizing though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127129/discussion-between-tristansokol-and-thailey01).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error, even on a phone running 4.4.4. Is there a video or screenshots you could send? Are you able to reproduce on any other kind of device?

Comment: I got the problem on my app on all Android devices I tested. I will give screenshots asap

Comment: Any chance you are running some kind of ad blocker that might be affecting it?

Comment: Not on my android devices. I get the problem when I run my android app too. I'm totally at a loss of what it could be. I guess the best thing I can do now is create a seperate page with the form and see if that works for me

Comment: @tristansokol just bought an s7 edge and my app and your link still dont format correctly.

Comment: @tristansokol I just tested your link on my phones samsung browser and the inputs worked like they were supposed to. This leads me to believe the problem lies in Chrome and Android webview. Does that help at all?

Comment: Which version of android and chrome do you have on your s7?

Comment: android version 6.0.1, chrome version 54.0.2840.85

Comment: Thanks! I was able to reproduce on a s7. Will update soon

Comment: Still working on it!

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Comment: How's the progress?